# Does it make sense to only use next omitting error and completed in Angular observable?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, angular-services

I have a method in my service as shown below. In there, I'm managing both *next* and *error*. However, since I want to spare my users from the actual error messages, I only wish to show the outcome of the operation. That's why I chose to emit a boolean value mapping the success to true and failure to false.

```
logIn(userName: string, password: string): Observable<boolean> {
  const headers = new HttpHeaders({ userName: userName, password: password });

  return new Observable(_ => {
    this.client.post(environment.API + "Admin/LogIn", null, { headers: headers })
      .subscribe(
        next => _.next(true),
        error => _.next(false));
  });
}
```

Then I figured, the only possible outcome in the consuming component is success, since any outcome in the underlying service is mapped to *next*. I also know that I'll be receiving a single value (making the usage of observables a bit overkill). So, I implemented the following consumer.

```
this.service.logIn(this.userName, this.password)
  .subscribe(
    next => { ... }
  );
```

Is it a wise approach in this particular case or am I missing something rather critical without realizing it? (It seems great to me but sometimes a stroke of genius might turn out to be just a stroke...)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need too much logic in subscribe if the chain is formed well. In your case if success use map/do and if error use catch operator instead

```
this.service.logIn(this.userName, this.password)
.do(... do your success handling)
.catch(e=>{
   ... do you error handling logic
   return Observable.of(e)})
.subscribe();
```

Comment: I'm not sure how it relates to my question. In your example, it seems nothing to be done in the subscribe part (where the logic must reside as it depends on the outcome of the service delivery). Please elaborate in case I'm missing the point.

Comment: what you return from subscribe is a subscription, it leaves you with very little flexibility to further handle the logic. If you use operator to handle the logic you can divert/combine your chain with other operation. you said "  the only possible outcome in the consuming component is success," is not true, you can use catch to handle error too.

Comment: I maybe was unclear with the error part. What I mean is that in the context of the component that contacts the service, the only outcomes that it's interested in is whether it went well (true being returned) or not (false being returned). Whether the service achieved is a bit of "fire and forget" situation (almost). So the question is whether it makes sense to handle all exceptions in the server and allow for the component not to care about error management (since, as I hope, it's managed in the service instead).

Comment: Normally both backend and  frontend code should handle errors because there maybe different types of them. What server should do is to fire an error with the corresponding status code 400, 500 and message in the json to let the frontend handle it.

Comment: Yes, I agree. But I'm talking about a service that's on the front-end. It's a part of my Angular project. It does contact an actual server-side backend and provides stuff to it. So the error management is done in the backend as well as the (service of) frontend in the application. My question regards managing the errors in the *xxx.component.ts* versus *yyy.service.ts*.